Proving that a set of polynomial functions ${f_1, f_2, ..., f_n}$ such that $f_k(x) = x^k$ is linearly independent, why is it the case?
This is originally an example of an infinite basis for the space of polynomial functions, V, over F, which is a subspace of the complex numbers.
The point I do not get is the following:
Proving that the set of functions ${f_1, f_2, ..., f_n}$ such that $f_k(x)  = x^k$ is linearly  independent, we have to show that if
$$ c_0x + c_1 x^1+...c_n x^n = 0 $$
then $$c_j = 0  \space \space \forall j \space \space \in \space \space {1,...,n}$$
Why does this follow from the fact that a
polynomial of degree n with complex coefficients cannot have more than n
distinct roots ?
That is what I do not get completely, I'd appricate any help.

Fundamental theorem of algebra says that $\sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^k$ has at most $n$ distinct roots

If a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n+1$ roots (or more), it must be the zero polynomial.

It can't be zero everywhere if it's only zero at finitely many points.

When you write $c_0 + c_1 x + \ldots + c_n x^n = 0$, that implies it  $0$ for all $x$.  So this polynomial doesn't have just $n$ roots, it has infinitely many.

Take any $n+1$ different complex numbers, say $z_1,z_2,\ldots, z_{n+1}\in\mathbb{C}$.
If $$c_0x + c_1 x^1+...c_n x^n \equiv 0$$
then plugging in $z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}$ we have $$c_0z_1 + c_1 z_1^1+...c_n z_1^n = 0\\\vdots\\c_0z_{n+1}+ c_1 z_{n+1}^1+...c_n z_{n+1}^n = 0$$
Therefore, $c_0x + c_1 x^1+...c_n x^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with more than $n$ roots, so it must be the constant polynomial equal to $0$, and thus all its coefficients are $0$ too.

This really help to understand that step, thank you!

$0$ in the vector space of polynomials over the complex numbers is the $0$ function. Ie. it is the function $Z: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $Z(x)=0$ for all $x$.
Thus $Z$ has infinitely many roots, even though every polynomial with nonzero coefficients has finitely many roots. This means that $Z$ is exactly the zero polynomial, so the powers of $x$ are a basis.
